# using window.open with angular 2 throw Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

building an application using angular 13+
and in one of the use cases, I need to open a link in a popup.
but just calling `window.open("https://www.google.com", "popup", "width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200")` throw an exception
`ERROR TypeError: Illegal invocation at Object.windowOpener`

already spend 2 days looking for a way to solve it but I'm still at the same point.

In my component Html file, I have this button

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" (click)="openPopup()">open</button>
```

and in my component.ts file, I have this function

```
  openPopup(): void {
    window.open("https://www.google.com", "popup", "width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200");}
```

nothing complicated here and already tested on Stackblitz and it works fine

also in html I used native `onClick="openPopup()"` event and implement the function in the javascript side and got the same error.

Comment: Isn't that the browser issue? I believe that Chrome is blocking such attempts by default. Have you tried it in different browsers?

Comment: tried in different browsers (firefox, edge) having the same issue. try it in Stackblitz and it works fine. really weird